# Undefined reference error even though the functions are present

Tags: c++, qt, bison

Although "Undefined Reference error" questions have been asked several times, I couldn't find solution to my problem.

I am trying to get flex and bison to work in a Qt app. I am facing problem in linking only.

These are the relevant files-

1) **icd.l** - Lex specification - It generates **iclexer.c** and contains definition of functions-

```
void yyerror(char const *s){...}
void* setUpBuffer(char const* text){...}
void tearDownBuffer(void* buffer){...}
int nextToken(){...}
```

2) **iclexer.h**

```
#ifndef ICLEXER_H
#define ICLEXER_H

extern void  yyerror(char const *);
extern int   yylex();
extern char* yytext;
extern void* setUpBuffer(char const* text);
extern void  tearDownBuffer(void* buffer);
extern int nextToken();

#endif // ICLEXER_H
```

3) **icparser.h**

```
#ifndef ICPARSER_H
#define ICPARSER_H
#include "iclexer.h"
#include <string>

extern void initLexer(std::string const& t);
extern void clearLexer();
extern int yyparse();

class Parser
{
public:
    Parser(std::string const& s)
    {
        initLexer(s);
    }
    void parse()
    {
        yyparse();
    }
    ~Parser()
    {
        clearLexer();
    }
};
#endif // ICPARSER_H
```

4) **icd.y** - Bison specification - It generates **icparser.cpp** and contains definition of functions-

```
void initLexer(std::string const& t);
void clearLexer();
int yylex();
```

In my GUI code I include **icparser.h** and use `class Parser`'s interface. But I am getting following error-

> /home/vinayak/codes/qt/dic_sim/icparser.cpp:1402:
>   error: undefined reference to `yyerror(char const*)'

And similar errors for `setUpBuffer(char const* text);`, `tearDownBuffer(void* buffer);` and `nextToken();`. Basically the functions in **iclexer.c** are not getting linked properly.

Please tell me how to either modify this code or how to change linking order in Qt (Qt Creator)?

Comment: Are you compiling and linking all of your binaries? Are you using `extern "C"` around the C declarations?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: All the files are added to the project so I believe -- all the binaries are compiled and linked. No I am not using `extern "C"` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the generated header file is exactly as stated, i.e. without any `extern "C"` then the problem you might be facing is that the C compiler will generate an unmangled symbol when compiling the function, but the C++ compiler will generate a dependency to the mangled name. The linker will see the dependency and the symbol, but not having the same name it will fail to match them together.

Take a look at the documentation of the tool used to generate the code and find how to generate C++ compatible code (usually just requires the inclusion of extra `extern "C"` code in the headers).

Comment: Thanks! I configured Flex to emit C++ code and it worked. The output did contain `extern "C"`

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your `error: undefined reference to 'yyerror(char const*)'`, you might want to read the Bison documentation, and more specifically [the part about yyerror](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#C_002b_002b-Parser-Interface). It reads:

```
— Method on parser: void error (const location_type& l, const std::string& m)

The definition for this member function must be supplied by the user: the parser
uses it to report a parser error occurring at l, described by m.
```

This definition is probably missing in your code. Note that `yyerror` is actually `yy::parser::error`, with `yy::` the parser's default namespace (which can be changed with `%define namespace "foo"`)and `parser::` the parser class's name by default (which can be changed with `%define parser_class_name foo`).

Your other errors seem unrelated to Bison.

Edit: oh, you seem to be generating C parsers, not C++ parsers. Well, it's the same for C parsers: [yyerror is user-supplied](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Error-Reporting).

The following definition suffices in simple programs:

```
 void
 yyerror (char const *s)
 {
   fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
 }
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, by generating C++ parser instead I solved my problem.